# OpenERP default value for many2one relationship

Tags: odoo

Lets assume the following model

```
class visit(osv.Model):
_name = "visit"
_order = "date desc"
_rec_name = "date"
_columns = {
    'date': fields.datetime('Date/Time', required=True),
    'res_partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Client', required=True),
}
```

And we have the following view:

```
<record id="visit_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">visit.form.view</field>
  <field name="view_type">form</field>
  <field name="model">visit</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Visit">
      <field name="date" />
      <field name="res_partner_id" />
    </form>      
  </field>
</record>
```

I have extended the `res.partner` to display a list of visits within a notebook page. When I **Add an Item** to the visits page within the customer, how do I set the default value of the `res_partner_id` combobox to the current customer?

Comment: First, thank you.

As said, I extended the `res.partner` model and added the `visit` model above, so I can log the visits of each visitor/partner/client. When I open a client's form, from within that I open the visit form, I get a one2many_list widget that gives me options to select a visitor (partner object). What I want is not to have to select the partner from within the visit form. Rather, set the default to the current partner

I can remove the `res_partner_id` field from the view. However I don't want to sacrifice having the option to set the partner from another separate form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your question and comment, I would suggest you to use one2many relation between two objects and keep one2many list view inside partner, from where one can create the record , does not need to select the partner and record is created only for that partner.

Cheers,
Parthiv

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that but was kinda reluctant. Now I think that I'll do it this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google OpenERP _defaults (a dictionary) and default_get (a method).